# Wordpress: jQuery not loading

Tags: jquery, wordpress

In the contact form section of my wordpress site, i'm trying to disable the line break from the text area (e.keycode 13). Here's the jQuery i'm using:

**jQuery**

[image]

But the script doesn't seem to be loading properly; I get an error on the console as below:

**console**

[image]

Any ideas why this is happening? I'm using the plugin Header and Footer Scripts to add the script to my wordpress theme and i'm using Contact Form 7 for the form. 
Having searched a lot for the solution, this is my last hope so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If `contact_form.js` return an error 404 its not a jQuery error

Comment: Issue with the contact_form.js line no 52, can you please share the code of the file.

Comment: okay i played around with it a little more and i got rid of the error in the code. But now i'm getting 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME    

this error.

Comment: @Tristup i have shared the jquery code in the original post. link to imgur.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: instead of image add code block

Answer (score 1):

You missed out the DOT('.') in selector of jQuery :

```
jQuery('.wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea')
```

Here you missed out the DOT('.') with the selector **wpcf7-textarea** even you have missed out the same in many options. Please rectify that and try, hope this time will work. If not worked please post the issues with it.

Comment: Do you mean jQuery('.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-textarea') ?

Just did it and im still getting: 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME'

Comment: Where is the dot before  wpcf7-textarea. It should be Query('.wpcf7-form-control .wpcf7-textarea')

Comment: Yep, just added the dot to all instances of the selector and the error still persists.

Comment: share your code in codepen or anywhere else, to review the code

Comment: I have checked other part too, util.isBlank method was not working and send method was not working. Please check the codepen link I shared in last comment I replace and removed and its start working. If send method is written your end just uncomment the code at your end.

Comment: Okay so i went a bit of a different route and used a line counter instead. And now i've got another problem. @Tristup could you please take a look at my new answer.